# How to filter data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm newbie in firebase database.

I make some relations key in firebase like this:

- `chats/conversation_key`
- `members/conversation_key/array_of_user_uid`
- `messages/conversation_key/array_of_messages`

The question is: How to find members key if i already know user uid?

IE: I want to find `-KgePX_tcbDz9fU-kAZT` in members if i already have user uid `jEIAfqDpJjWWUUXaecSmMk3U7vu1`

[image: firebase database]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("members");
firebaseRef.orderByChild(userKey).equalTo(true/false).on("child_added", function(Data){
console.log(Data.val(), Data.key);
}
```

i am assuming that you are already aware of **on** or **once** method and child events also, if not then read them([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)), will help you a lot, otherwise above code will do your job

Comment: Thank you so much. It's work. But now i have problem with ".indexOn". Firebase told me should index `userKey`. In fact i known i need to do that, but i don't known how to index that dynamic generated key. Thank you.